# Java: what is better initialize a list in entity as null or empty list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, eclipselink

In this example http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html#jpaintro_entitymanager if an entity have a @OneToMany relationship. the List is initialized in the declaration like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "family")
private final List<Person> members = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

I used to not initialize entities lists in my code, and always have to check if null. So My Question is: Is initializing lists (relationships) as an empty list in the declaration is what needs to be done normally or what ? and Why ?

What I'm currently doning

```
private final List<Person> members
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the JPA API; JPA persists what is there in the OBJECT. This is basic java, and totally opinion-based

Comment: In general "null" and "empty" have different meanings even if the behavior for jpa remains the same. Null means it was never initialized while empty means there are no entries. So if you need to handle those 2 cases different, you can do, if not it doesnt matter which way you go. For example null can mean, that you never load the data you need and you can load it after checking for null. While "empty" means you already load the data but there are no entries.

Comment: " if not it doesnt matter which way you go" Thanks, Can you copy-paste the whole answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general "null" and "empty" have different meanings even if the behavior for jpa remains the same. Null means it was never initialized while empty means there are no entries. So if you need to handle those 2 cases different, you can do, if not it doesnt matter which way you go. For example null can mean, that you never load the data you need and you can load it after checking for null. While "empty" means you already load the data but there are no entries

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally decide based on your application logic whether to keep this list as empty or null.
One disadvantage with null is that in the places where you are not expecting this list as null, you have to add extra null checks in the application code.
One better way is to initialize your list using Collections. EMPTY_LIST.